# Kan extension along any functor implies adjoint exists

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, adjoint-functors

I trying to decide whether the existence of a, say, a left Kan extension along $i: C \to D$ for any functor $F: C \to E$ implies that $i$ has a right adjoint.

I have proven the converse, and I know that if left Kan extensions existed and were absolute, i.e. preserved by any functor $G: E \to E'$, then $Ran_{F}id_C$ would be the desired adjoint.

I initially looked for a counterexample, but this turned out to be unsuccessful. I really have no idea how to approach this unfortunately, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Max maybe this is something you are interested in or can help with?

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314042/adjunctions-are-kan-extensions .  I don't know the answer at the moment, although note : if $i$ is in fact a left adjoint (= has a right adjoint), then the Kan extensions $Lan_i F$ are all absolute. In other words, if $i$ has all Kan extensions along it, but some of them aren't absolute, then $i$ can't be a left adjoint. (1/2)

Comment: So two possible strategies are: find an example with non absolute extensions; or prove that with your hypotheses all extensions are absolute (specifically, you only need $Lan_i id_C$ to be absolute). [unrelated : I don't know if you @ was to me but I didn't get a notification, I just stumbled onto your question by chance ] (2/2)

Comment: @Max Was trying to get a hold of you, but I guess it doesn't work like that. And thanks for the possible strategies :). Do you have any intuition for what the answer might be?

Comment: My intuition about Kan extensions is not very good yet, but I would say that only imposing existence will not yield absoluteness, and so I would say there are counterexamples. But maybe some trick with some functor or comma category can yield the desired properties, so I'm not quite sure.

Comment: For instance I have a counterexample if you only require that for any $E$ *with binary coproducts* a Kan extension exists. Of course this is a much weaker requirement but in my poor intuition it suggests that there should be a counterexample

Comment: @Max That sounds interesting, you can post that if you want, and I'll accept it as an answer I guess :)

Comment: I'll keep thinking about it before getting to that (my example is not nearly as interesting as it sounds : it simply uses the definition of coproduct to interpret it as a left Kan extension)